# IDE and Dynamic memory

Tags: c++, memory, windows-10, ide, heap-memory

this may sound like a silly question but does anyone know if the memory used in heap from executing codes in an IDE will be freed after the program ends? If it is not automatically freed, is there a way to clean up the heap? Please kindly advise.

Comment: I just imagined all the computers on which poor programmer run a program and leaked memory forever...

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I remember having a memory cleaner program for Windows 3.11 that was able to reclaim most of the "lost" memory and then hand it back to the OS. Fun stuff :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does anyone know if the memory used in heap from executing codes in an IDE will be freed after the program ends?

Yes. Operating systems generally releases all resources allocated to a process when the process terminates. Note that this is not something specified by the C++ language nor is this behaviour C++ specific.

Whether the process started by an IDE or something else does not matter.